# find specific pattern (sequence) in string with any program

Tags: regex, string, search, match

I would need any way (with any FREE program) to find a pattern in a string.

For example:

I search `12321`

The string is `dkaowkdlertrelkjh`

The searchstring has a specific pattern (first and last character are the same, second and fourth are the same, third is different than all other characters)

In the string this is matched by the part `ertre` `dkaowkdl**ertre**lkjh` since it follows the same pattern.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: And what if there is no pattern ? How should it match 12345 ?

Comment: it should say that this pattern is not present.. but thats not the case.. i am searching a specific pattern in a very long string and i know that this pattern is present. but i do not know how to find it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it youself. It's not so hard, all we have to do is to find how to match repeating groups. I'm a python programmer, so my solution is on **python**.

With a help of [re module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re) we find out that we can name the group matched like that `(?P<name>...)` and then address it like `(?P=name)`.

This is it.
We will use as pattern descriptor letter pattern (not digits) - it's a bit easiear and gives us an ability  to store bit more groups in memory.

```
import re

def GenerateRegexp(patternDescription, anySequence='.+'):
  '''
  Creates string regexp, that will describe our ABCAB-pattern in terms of regexp
  '''
  used = []
  regexp = ""
  for character in patternDescription:
     if character not in used:
        regexp += "(?P<%s>%s)" % (character, anySequence)  # we should be more attentive here if we expect % here, we can use str.format instead, but still might have a problem with {} symbols
        used.append(character)
     else:
        regexp += "(?P=%s)" % character
  return regexp

def Matches(string, pattern):
    '''
    Returns a bool answer, wheter string matches our pattern
    '''
    r = generate_regexp(pattern)
    SearchPattern = re.compile(r)
    return bool(SearchPattern.match(string))
```

Example of use (check, whether aabbaabb string matches 'abab' template (1212 in your language)):

```
print Matches (patternDescription="abab", string="aabbaabb")
```